# Finding the total variation of $3x^2-2x^3$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I would appreciate if someone could help me to find the total variation of $3x^2-2x^3$ on $[-2,2]$. Thanks

Comment: You need to help us first.  What do you understand to be the definition of "total variation"?  Where do you get stuck applying it?

Comment: dont understand "Total variation"

Comment: It's the supremum of the set of variations of f(x) defined on say [a,b] with respect to any partition on [a,b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

(1) The given function is monotone ascending in $\;\left[0\,,\,\frac34\right]\;$

(2) The total variation (= t.v.) of a function in $\;[a,b]\;$ equals the sum of its t.v. in $\;[a,c]\,,\,[c,b]\;,\;\;a<c<b$ .

**Another, much easier (perhaps) approach:**   If you already studied it, you can use the theorem that says the t.v. of $\;f\;$ in $\;[a.b]\;$ is

$$\int\limits_a^b|f'(x)|dx$$

as long as $\;f'(x)\;$ exists *and* is integrable Riemann in that interval.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that theorem which I found in Rudin's. But I was looking for a more general way of getting the answer like you explained. What if for any function given explicitly I find the the points where f attains a max or a min by differentiating and use those points for my partition will that do? @DonAntonio

Comment: Any given differentiable function that is

Comment: Well, what you propose is *exactly* how the theorem I mention is proved, @RajindaWickrama . You could also try the first approach as for a monotone function $\;f\;$ on $\;[a,b]\;$ the t.v. is almost trivially calculated: $\;f(b)-f(a)\;$ if monotone ascending, or minus that if monotone descending...